# Как создать кнопку при нажатии которой на виджете появиться еще одна кнопка

Tags: c++, qt

Создал в Qt проект с формой.
И мне надо что бы при нажатии кнопки появилась 
чуть ниже еще одна кнопка (для начала хотел бы что бы она просто появилась не в отдельном виджете (этого я достиг)) на том же  виджете.

**mainwindow.h:**

```
 #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
 #define MAINWINDOW_H

 #include <QMainWindow>

 namespace Ui {
 class MainWindow;
 }

 class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
 {
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

 private:
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
 };

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp:**

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include <QApplication>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication a(argc, argv);
     MainWindow w;
     w.show();

     return a.exec();
 }
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{

QPushButton* button2 =  new QPushButton;
button2->show();

//        QLineEdit* linia = new QLineEdit;
//        ui->tab_3->linia->show();
//        linia->show();
}
```

Я даже нормально не могу сформировать правильно вопрос :). По этому такое оформление. Прочитал `Шлее и Бланшет Ж., Саммерфилд М.`, и не нашёл там ответа. Подскажите пожалуйста. 
Если будет хотя бы какая нибуть статья или книга по теме "создание элементов создающих элементы" пожалуйста дайте ссылку .

Спасибо. С праздником.

Comment: что-нибудь типа `button2->setParent(this.centralWidget());` перед `show()` нее поможет?

Comment: Получаете указатель с `ui` на какой-нибудь layout (QVBoxLayout или QHBoxLayout), создаете кнопку и добавляете кнопку в layout используя метод addWidget

Comment: Спасибо gil9red   ваш ответ тоже помог :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно для вашего примера всё просто (скопировал ваш код), это самый простой вариант, ещё можно добавить эти кнопки в какие-нибудь слои(вертикальной растяжки и горизонтальной)

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{

QPushButton* button2 =  new QPushButton("Text", this);
QRect geoButton2; //Класс прямоугольника
geoButton2.setX(ui->pushButton->x());
//Задаём Х координату равной Х координате первой кнопки
geoButton2.setY(ui->pushButton->y()+ui->pushButton->height()+6);
//Задаём Y координату равной Y первой кнопки + высота первой кнопки + 6 пикселей
geoButton2.setWidth(100); //Ширина второй кнопки
geoButton2.setHeight(24); //Высота второй кнопки
button2->setGeometry(geoButton2); //Задаём геометрию кнопке
button2->show();

//        QLineEdit* linia = new QLineEdit;
//        ui->tab_3->linia->show();
//        linia->show();
}
```

Comment: Это очень плохой вариант. Нужно использовать layout'ы, чтобы размеры и положения виджетов автоматически менялись при изменении размеров окна или структуры окна

Comment: @gil9red как раз в ТЗ и не было указано про позиционирование элементов,